# How could I write a Perl script to calculate the MD5 sum of every file in a directory?

Tags: perl, unix, md5, md5sum

Is there any way to write a Perl script to calculate the MD5sum of every file in a directory?

If so, how could I do this?

Comment: Get a list of the files in the directory. Read each one. Calculate the md5sum of the contents. Print it.

Comment: How can I access the ls command from perl?  SHould I read the contents of the list into an array?  Then, is it possible to use the system's md5sum command on each filename stored in the array?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well there are many ways to do this but it comes down to two operations you need to preform. You will first need to locate a list of the files you would like to run the check and then you will need to run the md5sum check on each of those files. There is a ton of ways to do this but the following should work for your needs.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Digest::MD5 qw(md5_hex);

my $dirname = "/home/mgreen/testing/";
opendir( DIR, $dirname );
my @files = sort ( grep { !/^\.|\.\.}$/ } readdir(DIR) );
closedir(DIR);

print "@files\n";

foreach my $file (@files) {
    if ( -d $file || !-r $file ) { next; }
    open( my $FILE, $file );
    binmode($FILE);
    print Digest::MD5->new->addfile($FILE)->hexdigest, " $file\n";
    close($FILE);
}
```

The above will grab the md5sum for each file in the directory and skip any sub-directories and print it to STDOUT. The MD5 checksum part is then done by the [Digest::MD5](http://perldoc.perl.org/Digest/MD5.html) module which is ultimately what I think you are looking for.

I do like your question though as it is open-ended with alot of possible solutions like all "How do I do this in perl?" questions so I am sure you will get alot of possible solutions and I will most likely update mine when I get home later.

Comment: "The above will grab the md5sum for each file in the directory..."  Aren't you calculating the md5sum for the file name and not the file?

Comment: It's usually better to use glob than angle brackets.

Comment: @Kenosis you are correct and I modified the code.

Comment: @stark yeah that is what I get for trying to answer in phone while on the bus.

Comment: i just tried this and i cannot get it to print $FILE and $file unless i put this script in the root directory of the files. if i place this scripts in the root of C:/ then set the directory to the directory of the files i need to check, it will print @files, but will not print $FILE or $file

Comment: @MattGreen how can i set this up so it will check each files MD5 against an array?

Comment: @james28909 can you post it in a new question as a continuation of this question? There is additional details such as what is in the array that will be needed to answer properly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe using `find` with `-exec` can do the job?

```
find . -name "*.*" -exec md5sum '{}' \;
```

The '{}' will be replaced with the name of each file.

Answer (score 0):

Use `opendir` and `readdir` or other `recursive method`. 
Here is an example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w
use warnings;
my $DIR_PATH="a";
opendir DIR, ${DIR_PATH} or die "Can not open \"$DIR_PATH\"\n";
@filelist = readdir DIR;


foreach $file (@filelist) {
  open(IN,"a/$file")or die "cannot open";
  while(<IN>){...}
  close IN;
}
```